# NSURLCache don't support file://?

Tags: ios, nsurlcache, local-files

I would like to load `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"2.html"]` in `UIWebView` use `NSURLCache`, the cachedResponseForRequest: function is executed and return a `NSCachedURLResponse` object which is performed correctly at http:// scheme.
But The `UIWebView` load failed finally. Did I miss some optional?

I want to use `UIWebView` load html file in a compressed file, and I do not expect to uncompress the files to disk. is there any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"2" withExtension:@"html"];
 NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
 NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
 [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseUrl];
```

Comment: I am sorry, but it isn't effective. It didn't load data from NSURLCache, and the html is still in compressed file.